# Making ScrollBar to scroll towards bottom when a message is sent using CustomTkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar, customtkinter

I have a scrollable frame, and a Label which I use to add text into the scrollable frame. How do I Make the ScrollBar to scroll towards bottom when a message is sent like messaging apps usually do ?
I cant use Canvas or any regular solutions since im using customtkinter

Here is My Code

```
from tkinter import *
import customtkinter as ctk
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


# Window
root = ctk.CTk()
root.geometry("350x500")
root.title("v2")
root.resizable(False, False)
ctk.set_appearance_mode("Light")

send_image_original = Image.open("send-message.png")  # Adding and resizing image for button
send_resize = send_image_original.resize((50, 50))
send_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(send_resize)


def Send_Message():  # Button send function
    message = entry.get()

    # Create a message bubble frame
    bubble_frame = ctk.CTkFrame(frame, width=250, corner_radius=20, fg_color="lightblue")
    bubble_frame.pack(anchor="e", padx=10, pady=5)  # Adjust the padx and pady values as needed

    # Create a label inside the bubble frame
    label = ctk.CTkLabel(bubble_frame, text_color="Black", text=message, font=("Helvetica", 14), bg_color="lightblue")
    label.pack(expand=True, fill="both", padx=10, pady=5)

    entry.delete(0, "end")


send = ctk.CTkButton(master=root, corner_radius=10, command=Send_Message, image=send_image, text="", fg_color="Blue",
                     width=30, height=40)
send.place(relx=0.8, rely=0.9, anchor=tk.CENTER)

frame = ctk.CTkScrollableFrame(master=root, width=300, height=350, corner_radius=10, fg_color="White")
frame.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.43, anchor=tk.CENTER)

entry = ctk.CTkEntry(master=root, width=200, height=50, corner_radius=10)
entry.place(relx=0.4, rely=0.9, anchor=tk.CENTER)


def on_enter_key(event):
    Send_Message()


entry.bind("<Return>", on_enter_key)
root.mainloop()
```

I tried using canvas and all other regular solutions but they wont work since it customtkinter

Comment: It's a bit of a hack, but looking through the [source code](https://github.com/TomSchimansky/CustomTkinter/blob/e116faf9108737ebe127236913286b0beb035871/customtkinter/windows/widgets/ctk_scrollable_frame.py#L53), it would seem like you can access the scrollbar via `frame._scrollbar`, and since it's a `CTkScrollbar`, you ought to be able to use `frame._scrollbar.set()` [see here](https://customtkinter.tomschimansky.com/documentation/widgets/scrollbar#setstart_value-end_value)

Comment: You can scroll the internal canvas to the end using `frame.after(10, frame._parent_canvas.yview_moveto, 1.0)`.  Using `.after()` to update `yview` after the canvas is updated.

Comment: scrolling the internal canvas to the end using frame.after(10, frame._parent_canvas.yview_moveto, 1.0) worked perfectly as I wanted it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

scrolling the internal canvas to the end using frame.after(10, frame._parent_canvas.yview_moveto, 1.0) worked perfectly as I wanted it.